Websocket and Pubsub client fails with senderror
PubsubClient::logs_subscribe fails randomly on websocket and its hard to debug. With nodeJS this works.
websocket fails with receive error: "SendError(..)"
use solana_client::pubsub_client::PubsubClient;

let addresses = vec![RAYDIUM_FEE.to_string()];
    let filter = RpcTransactionLogsFilter::Mentions(addresses);

    let (mut logclient, receiver) = PubsubClient::logs_subscribe(
        &wss_url.to_string(),
        filter,
        RpcTransactionLogsConfig {
            commitment: Some(CommitmentConfig::confirmed()),
        },
    )?;

https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/issues/1305
